# How to Add Callbacks for a QTWidget in ROS?

Tags: rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am intending to develop a user interface using rqt in ros. I have developed a user interface containing a QTPushButton and QTLabel in QT Designer. I have imported this ui file into my Python Plugin. So, when I run the plugin, the user interface does pop up. But now I want to add a callback to the PushButton. So, that if I press the Button then the label should show the text
"Button Clicked". I have tried many code snippets, but somehow nothing happens when I click the Button.

Can somebody please help. It is very urgent. Can somebody write the actual code for the callback.

My Plugin.py file is given below:

```
import os

import rospy

import rospkg
 
from qt_gui.plugin import Plugin

from python_qt_binding import loadUi

from python_qt_binding.QtGui import QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel

class MyPlugin(Plugin):
    
def __init__(self, context):
     
   super(MyPlugin, self).__init__(context)
      
   self.setObjectName('MyPlugin')  
        
    from argparse import ArgumentParser
        
    parser = ArgumentParser()
        
    parser.add_argument("-q", "--quiet", action="store_true", dest="quiet",
                         help="Put plugin in silent mode")
   
    args, unknowns = parser.parse_known_args(context.argv())
        
        if not args.quiet:
               print 'arguments: ', args
               print 'unknowns: ', unknowns
   
           # Create QWidget
        self._widget = QWidget()
           # Get path to UI file which should be in the "resource" folder of this package
        ui_file = os.path.join(rospkg.RosPack().get_path('rqt_mypkg'), 'resource', 'mainwindow.ui')
           # Extend the widget with all attributes and children from UI file
        loadUi(ui_file, self._widget)
  
        # Give QObjects reasonable names
        self._widget.setObjectName('MyPluginUi')
          # Show _widget.windowTitle on left-top of each plugin (when 
         # it's set in _widget). This is useful when you open multiple 
           # plugins at once. Also if you open multiple instances of your 
           # plugin at once, these lines add number to make it easy to 
           # tell from pane to pane.
        if context.serial_number() > 1:
               self._widget.setWindowTitle(self._widget.windowTitle() + (' (%d)' % context.serial_number()))
           # Add widget to the user interface
        context.add_widget(self._widget)
        
        self.text = QLabel("Data")
         pushButton = QPushButton("Click Here")
        pushButton.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
        
         
    def buttonClicked(self):
        print("Button Clicked")
        self.text.setText("Button Has been Clicked")
```

Also, my ui file looks like this "mainwindow.ui":

```
<ui version="4.0">
  <class>Form</class>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
    <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <width>400</width>
        <height>300</height>
      </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="windowTitle">
      <string>Form</string>
    </property>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
      <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
          <x>80</x>
          <y>180</y>
          <width>98</width>
          <height>27</height>
        </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
        <string>PushButton</string>
      </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
      <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
          <x>100</x>
          <y>80</y>
          <width>66</width>
          <height>17</height>
        </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
        <string>TextLabel</string>
      </property>
    </widget>
  </widget>
  <resources/>
  <connections/>
</ui>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195152/how-to-add-callbacks-for-a-qtwidget-in-ros?/) by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2014-10-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-16**:
It looks like you're creating a new button rather than retrieving the existing button that is created by the UI file.

**Comment by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on 2014-10-16**:
Can you tell me how to reference the button from the UI File?

**Comment by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on 2014-10-16**:
Can somebody please help?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-16**:
I don't know how to retrieve a button that is created by the UI file offhand, but it shouldn't be hard to find a QT tutorial online.

**Comment by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on 2014-10-16**:
I have searched the web for the last 2 days. But could not find a way of referencing the buttons from the ui file. I hope somebody else would be able to answer. It should be easy I suppose.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-16**:
I did this search: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=python+qt+use+ui+file and the first link (for me) looks like a fairly good reference: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html .

**Comment by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on 2014-10-16**:
Thanks. I would have a look at these.

**Comment by [Aaron Blasdel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3372/aaron-blasdel/) on 2014-10-17**:
There is a helper function in python_qt_binding called loadUi that will make things easier and more portable than those links. I have detailed its use below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rqt system uses the "LoadUi" helper function to load ui files from python_qt_binding

It is imported like so:

```
from python_qt_binding import loadUi
```

And called like this:

```
ui_file = *PATH TO YOUR UI FILE*
my_widget = *WIDGET TO LOAD YOUR UI FILE INTO*
loadUi(ui_file, my_widget)
```

Each widget is loaded as a child widget to "my_widget" and it can be accessed using the name you gave it in the ui_file as so:

```
my_widget.load_button.hide()
my_widget.save_button.setText('')
```

Then simply connect the relevant callbacks as so:

```
my_widget.load_button.clicked.connect(self.load_callback_function)
```

If you want to see a working example please look at rqt_msg here:

```
https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/blob/groovy-devel/rqt_msg/src/rqt_msg/messages_widget.py
https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/blob/groovy-devel/rqt_msg/resource/messages.ui
```

---

Originally posted by [Aaron Blasdel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3372/aaron-blasdel/) with karma: 211 on 2014-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on 2014-10-17**:
Thanks. Yes, I have got this working now. I did not know that each widget would be a child widget of my_widget as in this case.

Thanks to you anyway. It was quite easy in the end.